# Mule 3.6 with JTDS insertion in to SQl Server

Tags: sql-server, mule, jtds

Its a basic mule Database Connector where i am using a JTDS driver to insert in to Database. I get the below error, I observed if i hard code it to some value it gets inserted, But if i want to dynamically send it with payload:'column name' I get the below error. I am using it in the wrong way, i tried everything. Please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

```
INFO  2015-07-28 14:47:15,461 [[mule_edesk_integration].Pricing_Integration.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ==========>Inserted  Data   :  22733.0,102520                    ,FRR ,1082838       ,USD,28.0
ERROR 2015-07-28 14:47:15,583 [[mule_edesk_integration].Pricing_Integration.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Unable to convert value 22733.0 to NULL. (java.sql.SQLException). Message payload is of type: CaseInsensitiveHashMap
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Unable to convert value 22733.0 to NULL. (java.sql.SQLException)
  net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Support:742 (null)
2. Unable to convert value 22733.0 to NULL. (java.sql.SQLException). Message payload is of type: CaseInsensitiveHashMap (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor:93 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert value 22733.0 to NULL.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Support.convert(Support.java:742)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setObjectBase(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:590)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setObject(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:913)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: This is not a Mule exception and rather an SQL exception. What is the data type of your source and destination? You may need to add a transformation in your code to fix this issue. If you could post your XML and share data types, I can check closely on what may be causing an issue.

Comment: I understand it is not a mule error but why is it trying to convert 22733.0 in to NULL is puzzling to me. If I used the following insert    insert into table (ppr_sequence) values (#[payload.ppr_sequence.toString()]) It DOes not insert and gives that error and if I use it as insert into oima_repair_price (ppr_sequence)
values ('22733.0') it inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "from Template" option instead. A little more tedious but works.